# What does "|| [];" mean?

Tags: javascript

What does `|| []` mean in the code below? Why might this be needed?

```
getPair: function() {
    return this.props.pair || [];
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

`[]` is an empty array. `||`, in this context, is a guard operator.

The statement says to return `this.props.pair`, but if `this.props.pair` is falsy, an empty array will be returned instead.